# scala lift - filterNot with multiple arguments

Tags: scala, lift

I have the following filter on a List:

```
 messages = messages.filterNot(m => m.room == room)
```

What I'm trying to do is have multiple arguments so I can match all items that have the same room ID and the same data value, so something like:

```
 messages = messages.filterNot(m => m.room == room, m.data == data)
```

This doesnt work of course, is there a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated :)

Comment: something like `messages.filterNot(m => m.room == room && m.data == data)`?

Comment: @4e6: make an answer of your comment and let *sirjamm* accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can deal with it

1. straightforward

   ```
   messages.filterNot(m => m.room == room && m.data == data)
   ```
2. chaining filters

   ```
   messages.filterNot(_.room == room).filterNot(_.data == data)
   ```
3. using [WithFilter](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike$WithFilter.html) which applies restrictions on original collection instead of creating intermediate ones

   ```
   messages.withFilter(_.room != room).withFilter(_.data != data) map identity
   ```